# Xampp and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xampp

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server via PHP, however, I keep getting errors in my code which found out was due to the SQL Server driver. But that's not the issue, the issue I am having now is XAMPP will not run the driver and when checking PHP info it won't show that the drivers are running.

To find a copy of my PHP.ini please go to the following link:http://linustechtips.com/main/topic/376252-xampp-568-with-ms-sql/

Comment: Why are moderators changing how my question? Sure if I got something or worded something wrong is fine, but one removed the word "Thanks" off the end :/

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no official driver for PHP 5.6.  Found a unofficial driver..

Hope this works, please check this out..

[Unofficial Microsoft SQL Server Driver for PHP (sqlsrv)](http://robsphp.blogspot.be/2012/06/unofficial-microsoft-sql-server-driver.html)

Comment: Thanks, I am fairly sure the drivers are running now. their must be official drivers I downloaded them from Microsoft :/ I'm a wee confused